# What is the best approach to load a long array into an arrayadapter?

Tags: android, listview

I want to display 2000 strings from a resource file into a list.  In order to conserve memory I don't want to create an array of 2000 strings and pass it into the arrayadapter constructor.  So I'm considering setting an [InfiniteScrollListener](http://www.avocarrot.com/blog/implement-infinitely-scrolling-list-android/) to the listview to load the strings in by segments of 10.

My loadData method would return the next set of 10 strings in the resource file until EOF.  When EOF is reached:

1. loadData() simply returns null, and
2. loadMore() breaks out with a return statement.

Is this the best approach in my situation?

Comment: cannot you use `BaseAdapter` that loads the data on demand (lazy load pattern)?

Comment: You may not need to conserve memory for this use case. Look up how large your resource file is. That will be (approximately) the amount of memory that when using a string array. Unless your file is measured in many megabytes you probably do not have to worry about it.

Comment: @RobMeeuwisse yeah I just noticed loadMore() contains "dataList.addAll".  Is there a way for me to only create arrays for the adapter as long as what is visible/about to be visible?

Comment: If you want to load just the data that you need to be visible then you will have to go the custom adapter path, like @pskink said. You should remember though, that the user can also scroll backwards, so you cannot just load the 'next chunk of data' because it may be a previous chunk (or random chunk) of data. And unless your text file has lines that are all the same length, it will be hard for you to figure out which part of the file to read for the chunk of data you need. This is a tough problem to solve. You may want to double check if you really have to solve it.

Comment: did you try to lazy load the data in BaseAdapter#getItem() ?

Comment: @pskink if I understand what you mean by lazy load(convertView == null) check, that wont help because to create the adapter I'd still need a list of 2000 strings to begin with instead of reading from the resource file as the user scrolls the list.

Comment: no, lazy load == implementing loading data in `BaseAdapter#getItem()`